# Why do no prime ideals ramify in the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p }, \sqrt{q})/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{pq })$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let $p,q $ be odd integer primes, $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

$K = \mathbb{Q }[\sqrt{pq }]$, $L = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{p }, \sqrt{q} ]$. Why a prime ideal in $O_{K}$ doesn't ramify in $O_{L} $ ?

My thoughts : I calculated the field discriminants $d_{K } = 4pq $, $d_{L } = 16p^{2 }q^{2 }$, so a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z }$ which ramify in  $O_{L} $ already ramifies in $O_{K}$.

Comment: $ \{ 1, \sqrt{ pq} \} $ is an integral basis for $O_{K}$, so we can calculate $d_{K}$ using this integral basis. Is it correct ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that $p \equiv 1 $  ( mod $4$ ) and $q \equiv 3 $ ( mod $ 4$ )

Comment: It is, indeed, relatively rare that no primes ramify in an extension of number fields, but it does happen. Class field theory studies questions such as these. Here (when reinterpreted suitably) the infinite primes (real embeddings of a field) do "ramify". The maximal extension $M$ of a given field $K$ such that no primes (finite nor infinite) ramify in $M/K$ is called the Hilbert Class field. It is known that $[M:K]=h_K$, the class number of $K$. I am too ignorant to say much more about it. I did enjoy studying the topic from [Milne's notes](http://jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/cft.html).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:  One correction:  The Hilbert class field is only the maximal <em>abelian</em> such extension.  It's quite possible to have unramified extensions even when $h_K=1$.

Comment: Oops. Thanks, @Cam. On a good day I might have remembered to add that bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dQ}{\mathbb{Q}}\newcommand{\fp}{\mathfrak{p}}\newcommand{\fq}{\mathfrak{q}}\newcommand{\cO}{\mathcal{O}}$
Note that if $K=\dQ(\sqrt{pq})$, then $L=\dQ(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q})$ is just $K(\sqrt{p})=K(\sqrt{q})$. To see that $L/K$ is unramified, we just have to show that for each prime $\fp$ of $K$ and each prime $\fq\mid \fp$ of $L$, the extension $L_\fq/K_\fp$ is unramified. Since $L/\dQ$ is only ramified above $p$ and $q$, we only need to check those $\fp$ which lie above $p$ or $q$. Suppose $\fp\mid p$. Then $\cO_{L_\fq}=\cO_{K_\fp}[\sqrt{q}]$, but since $\cO_{K_\fp}$ has residue characteristic $p$, the extension $\cO_{K_\fp}[\sqrt{q}]/\cO_{K_\fp}$ is unramified. Similarly, if $\fp\mid q$, one writes $\cO_{L_{\fq}}=\cO_{K_\fp}[\sqrt{p}]$ to see that $L_\fq/K_\fp$ is unramified.

So essentially, one uses $L=K[\sqrt p]$ to see that $L/K$ is unramified away from $p$, and $L=K[\sqrt q]$ to see that $L/K$ is unramified away from $q$. This forces $L/K$ to be unramified.

Comment: what do you mean by residue characteristic ?

Comment: @boris the residue characteristic of a local ring $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ is the characteristic of the residue field $A/\mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is also ramified above $2$.

Comment: @Daniel  How does the fact that $\cO_{K_\fp}$ has residue characteristic $p$ imply that the extension $\cO_{K_\fp}[\sqrt{q}]/\cO_{K_\fp}$ is unramified ?

Comment: @boris Because the polynomial $x^2-q$ splits in the residue field? cf. [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38431/dedekinds-theorem-on-the-factorisation-of-rational-primes).