# Prime ideals over $p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory

It's given a finite extension $F$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ and suppose it's ring of integers is in the form $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ for some integrer $x$. For each prime $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ proof there are at most $p$ prime ideals $P_i$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $P_i\cap\mathbb{Z}=p\mathbb{Z}$ and $dim_{\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}}(\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{P_i})=1$  (for $i=1,\ldots,p$).

Appreciated even ideas and suggestions cause I have no ideas on how start this proof.

Comment: Are you sure the question's right? The number of primes above $p$ relates to $[F:\mathbb{Q}]$, and can be at most this value. I'm sure there must be an example where there are more than 2 primes above 2, although I'm not sure how the ring of integers being monogenous comes into this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f(t)\in {\mathbb Z}[t] $ is the irreducible monic polynomial corresponding to your generator $x$ of the ring of  integers of $F$. By
[Dedekind's theorem on the factorisation of rational primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38431/dedekinds-theorem-on-the-factorisation-of-rational-primes),
the  distinct primes above $p$ correspond to the distinct irreducible factors of $\bar f ( t )$ mod $p$. The prime factors $ P$ above $p$ of degree $1$ (i.e., matching your dimension criterion above) are in bijection with the  linear factors of $\bar f$. These are of the form $(t - a)$, for $a\in {\mathbb F}_p$, so there can be no more than $p$ such factors, and thus no more than $p$ such primes $P$.